# AJAX error function not throwing when db match not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

UPDATED:

I have a code entry box that tried to find a match in a database. If a match is found, evrything works, but when a match is not found, I am having issues. See my code and results for a good and bad match below.

Here is my code:

```
function codeMatchTest() {
var discount;
if ($('#dbReturnString').val() == '') {
    alert("Please enter a discount code.");
} else {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PROMO.svc/MatchCode",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ codeInput: $('#dbReturnString').val().toLowerCase() }),
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json.d);
        console.log(json.d[0].DISCOUNT);
        discount = JSON.parse(json.d);
        console.log(discount);
        console.log(json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"]);
        console.log(returnCustID());
        if (discount != null) {
            discount = discount[0].DISCOUNT;
        } else {
            alert("Not a valid code.");
            discount = 1;
        }
        //            alert("First: " + json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"] + " / Second: " + discount + " / Third: " + json.d);
        //            console.log("First: " + json.d[0]["DISCOUNT"] + " / Second: " + discount + " / Third: " + json.d);
        //            console.log(discount * 20);
    },
    error: function (json) {
        alert("There was an error with your request.");
    }
});
}
console.log(discount);
return discount;
}
```

Here are the console results for a good entry:
[{"DISCOUNT":0.5}] 
undefined 
[Object]
0: Object
DISCOUNT: 0.5
**proto**: Object
length: 1
**proto**: Array[0]
undefined 
27382 
0.5

Here are results for a bad, non-matching entry:
[] 
undefined 
[] 
undefined 
27382 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DISCOUNT' of undefined

When a bad entry is made, "[]" is returned, which I think it just an empty json array, but it also says "undefined' for json.d. I am all sorts of confused now. I have tried many different ways to say if (json.d is empty, null, not = to a number, etc....) and nothing seems to work. Tring conditional such as `if(discount[0].DISCOUNT >= 0) { run good code }` doesn't work either, beucase the 'undefined' or '[]' result for some reason passes this condition. But it's empty, and not >= 0!!!

Any help is appreciated. This seems so simple and is causing me such trouble.

Comment: My return is inaccurate above - forgot I changed some things around. This is on my console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DISCOUNT' of undefined promo.js:46
$.ajax.success promo.js:46
c jquery-1.10.2.js:5
p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:5
k jquery-1.10.2.js:14
r jquery-1.10.2.js:14
send jquery-1.10.2.js:14
x.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.2.js:14
codeMatch promo.js:35
updateTotal cart.js:292
applyPromo promo.js:234
onclick

Comment: If you click "edit" you can update your question directly rather than trying to cram that new information into a comment.

Comment: Create a set of error codes and check that in your `success` handler.

Comment: Noted. Didn't see that I could edit my posts.

Answer (score 1):

The `error` handler is only called if the server returns an HTTP error status (e.g., 404, 500, etc). You will either have to adjust the service to return an HTTP error status if there is no match in the service, or adjust your `success` handler to inspect the value of the result and treat an empty response appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. The console says "cannot read property 'DISCOUNT' of undefined" - so if the return is simply undefined, would it be an empty json array? At one point I was getting "[]" returned, which would seem to make sense.

Comment: The actual data returned will depend on your service implementation. An empty array is one logical possibility, but it could also return no payload at all.

Comment: I have tried everything to handle the empty json result. It is either '[]' or 'undefined' depending on what I send to the console. I have tried conditionals with both but always get errors. How do I handle either '[]' or 'undefined'? I updated my code and console results above to show where I get these results. I simply want to say if{discount = '[]') { alert("Not valid entry.") } else { run good code }

Comment: If you're only interested in falsy-ness, then use something like `if (!discount || discount.length === 0) {/*invalid*/} else {/*valid*/}`